# How do I align the text with the center or approximately near it?

Tags: html, css

How can I make `id=latest_tweet` to come somewhere in the centre of `id=logo` ?

*Note: I am trying horizontal alignment, with image to the left and latest_tweet to its right but in the center.*

*HTML:*

```
<div id="header">
        <span id="logo"> <img src="twibuffer.gif" alt="twibuffer"  /> </span>
        <span id="latest_tweet"> Latest Tweet:</span>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#header {
   margin-bottom:2%;
}

#latest_tweet {
   margin-left:40%;
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: @vishnurajv no.Horizontally

Comment: is it allowed to include the width of the logo in a CSS definition?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/2jpDw/2/show
http://jsfiddle.net/2jpDw/2

```
#header {
  text-align: center;
}

#header span {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Try again for the links. Should be fine now.

Comment: Buffer should be on left and latest tweet to its right but in the center

Comment: You should mention than vertical alignment.

Comment: So center both horizontally and logo + text on their turn vertically.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7ahhL/3/)**</kbd>

css

```
.block {
    text-align: center;
}
.centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#header {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#latest_tweet {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="centered"> 
        <span id="header"> 
            <img src="http://numenta.org/images/stackoverflow.png" alt="twibuffer"/> 
            <span id="latest_tweet">Latest Tweet</span> 
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set the two inner divs `display:inline;` of `display:inline-block;` and set the #header `text-align:center;`.

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/uphvj/)**